# Odoo Orm date filter?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

How can I filter the orm by today, this month and last month?
something like:

```
a = self.env['model.model'].search_read([today])
a = self.env['model.model'].search_read([this_month])
a = self.env['model.model'].search_read([last_month])
```

Comment: And what is the name of the field that you want to filter with. And do you want to use search or read?

Answer (score 0):

One way to filter a `Recordset` in Odoo is to use the `filtered` method [1].

This works the exact same way, the python `filter` method can be used [2].

You can call it on the Recordset your search returns with a custom filter method, which could look like this:

```
def filter_by_day(c_date, d_date):
  if (d_date.year == c_date.year)
    and (d_date.month == c_date.month)
    and (d_date.day == c_date.day):
      return True
  else:
    return False
```

You call this method using `filtered` on your Recordset like so:

```
rs = env['model.model'].search([])
rs.filtered(lambda r: filter_by_day(r.create_date, datetime.datetime.now()))
```

This returns a filtered recordset you can display.

[1] https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#filter

[2] https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter